# Android service not restarted when app back from idle state

Tags: android, service, background, android-8.0-oreo

I've upgraded my app to API 26 and I'm facing some issues with the new [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).

On Oreo devices, as soon as my app goes in background, my app is stopped by the OS due to idle state as written in logs :

```
Stopping service due to app idle: u0a80 com.example.test/com.example.test.service1
Stopping service due to app idle: u0a80 com.example.test/com.example.test.service2
```

Then, I try to start my app again and the last activity is correctly restored (including its fragment, and all data displayed)

```
07-16 10:21:51.253 system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.test/com.example.test.activity1 bnds=[317,1159][586,1508]} from uid 10024
```

The issue is that my services are not restarted.

They both returns START_STICKY in the onStartCommand which should tell the OS that the service should be restarted after being killed as it is state in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this
>   service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state
>   but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to
>   re-create the service.

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Is it possible to restore the services without explicit calls to startService or bindService methods ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from Android O there is limitation on how freely app can access background Service. If your app is not running is foreground then the Services are terminated by OS, as if `stopSelf()` is called. That is the reason why `START_STICKY` won't rescue in this case.

You need to either restart the Service when Activity is created or create ForegroundService and execute until your task is completed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that's was not clear enough for me that the services are properly terminated by the OS.

Comment: Our foreground-notification was showing important information, **but** Android API 33+ no longer shows said notification; Is there any way to detect if Android shows foreground-notification, or is checking API -level >= 33 enough? (Then we could simply show normal notification for said info where required.)

Answer (score 1):

This might also occur when your app is set to being restricted to run in the background (go to the settings of your app and then to Battery, and look for the option 'allow background activity'). If the app is restricted, the service will automatically stop after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

When you occur this kind of logs :

> Stopping service due to app idle: u0a80
> com.example.test/com.example.test.service1

that's mean the Android OS system place your application in the list of applications must be optimized battery so it will be removed (closed).
To avoid this behavior you should place your app as authorized appliction can be running in background :

So you should add this permission in your manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

and in your activity :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private fun askIgnoreOptimizationsBattery() {
    val pm = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as? PowerManager
    if (pm != null && !pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
        val intent = Intent()
        val packageName = packageName
        intent.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS;
        intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName");
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```